# How to rotate a long table in a two column article?

Tags: longtable, pdfpages, landscape, elsarticle, pdflscape

I'm trying to achieve something like the table of the following article:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168169917308803

[image: article screenshot]

It's a two columns Elsevier review with a few long tables for the reviewed references with some descriptions.
I tried using pdflscape, rotatebox, longtable, supertabular, tabularx, but couldn't make it work. I'm using the Overleaf online editor and I believe I can manage it myself from a working example to make a basic horizontal, long table.
I appreciate any help!

Comment: you should be able to use `\onecolumn\begin{landscape}\begin{longtable{....\end{longtable}\end{landscape}\twocolumn`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks for your answer, this works fine, however, the pages are rendered in landscape orientation. I don't know if this is an Overleaf feature, as it is practical to read, but I believe journal's editors will ask to rotate those pages. Is this possible?

Comment: if you use the pdflscape package the pdf will have a hint to the viewer to turn those pages but not all viewers accept hint, almost all pdf viewers will have a menu option to rotate the view so you can read it. Note it's only a viewer hint if you (or the journal) print the document it will be unaffected and print the table sideways as your image shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OPTION 1** Inserting a landscape table that fits on the page.

This example shows a rotated table that fills the usable space of the page. It is collected in box and rotated.

Filling the table must be done manually to fit the page, in the sense that `longtable`'s automatic page break cannot be used because a `longable` is a float and will not work in a box.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[final,3p,twocolumn,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{graphicx} % rotatebox
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\footnotesize\raggedright \arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newlength{\twidth}
\setlength{\twidth}{\dimexpr \textheight+\headheight+\topsep} % total usable page height

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % only for dummy text
%\usepackage{showframe} % use to show the margins

\journal{Computers and Electronics in Agriculture}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}                 
    \title{The Title}                   
    \author{One Author}         
    \affiliation{organization={},
    addressline={}, 
    city={},
    postcode={}, 
    state={},
    country={}}         
    \begin{abstract}
        %% Text of abstract             
    \end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction }‎‎

1. \kant[1-4]

\clearpage  
    
\rotatebox{90}{%    
\hspace*{\dimexpr-0.8\columnwidth-\columnsep}\begin{minipage}{\textheight}  
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{L{3ex} L{0.20\twidth} L{0.35\twidth}L{0.42\twidth}@{}}
    No. & Application in Agriculture&   Remote sensing&     Techniques for data analysis\\
    \hline
    1.&     Soil and vegetation/crop mapping&   Hyperspectral imaging (satellite and airborne), multi‐spectral
    imaging (satellite), synthetic aperture radar (SAR)&    Image fusion, SVM, end-member extraction algorithm, co-polarized phase
    differences (PPD), linear polarizations (HH, VV, HV), distance-based    classification, decision trees, linear mixing models, logistic regression, ANN,     NDVI\\
    2.&     Leaf area index and crop canopy&    Hyperspectral imaging (airborne), multi‐spectral imaging (airborne) & Linear regression analysis, NDVI\\
    3.&     Crop phenology&     Satellite remote sensing (general)& Wavelet-based filtering, Fourier transforms, NDVI\\
    4.& 
    Crop height, estimation of yields,
    fertilizers' effect and biomass& 
    Light Detection and Ranging (LIDAR), hyperspectral and multi-
    spectral imaging, SAR, red-edge camera, thermal infrared& 
    Linear and exponential regression analysis, linear polarizations (VV),
    wavelet-based filtering, vegetation indices (NDVI, ICWSI), ANN\\
    5.& 
    Crop monitoring& 
    Satellite remote sensing (hyperspectral and multi-spectral imaging),
    NIR camera, SAR& 
    Stepwise discriminate analysis (DISCRIM) feature extraction, linear
    regression analysis, co-polarized phase differences (PPD), linear polarizations
    (HH, VV, HV, RR and RL), classification and regression tree analysis\\
    6.& 
    Identification of seeds and
    reorganization of species& 
    Remote sensing in general, cameras and photo-detectors,
    hyperspectral imaging& 
    Principal component analysis, feature extraction, linear regression analysis\\
    7.& 
    Soil and leaf nitrogen content and
    treatment, salinity detection& 
    Hyperspectral and multi-spectral imaging, thermal imaging& 
    Linear and exponential regression analysis\\
    8.& 
    Irrigation& 
    Satellite remote sensing (hyperspectral and multi-spectral imaging),
    red-edge camera, thermal infrared& 
    Image classification techniques (unsupervised clustering, density slicing with
    thresholds), decision trees, linear regression analysis, NDVI\\
    9.& 
    Plants water stress detection and drought
    conditions& 
    Satellite remote sensing (hyperspectral and multi-spectral imaging,
    radar images), thermal imaging, NIR camera, red-edge camera& 
    Fraunhofer Line Depth (FLD) principle, linear regression analysis, NDVI\\
    10.& 
    Water erosion assessment& 
    Satellite remote sensing (optical and radar images), SAR, NIR
    camera& 
    Interferometric SAR image processing, linear and exponential regression
    analysis, contour tracing, linear polarizations (HH, VV)\\
    11.& 
    Pest detection and management& 
    Hyperspectral and multi-spectral imaging, microwave remote
    sensing, thermal camera& 
    Image processing using sample imagery, linear and exponential regression
    analysis, statistical analysis, CEM nonlinear signal processing, NDVI\\
    12.& 
    Weed detection& 
    Remote sensing in general, optical cameras and photo-detectors,
    hyperspectral and multi-spectral imaging& 
    Pixel classification based on k-means clustering and Bayes classifier, feature
    extraction techniques with FFT and GLCM, wavelet-based classification and
    Gabor filtering, genetic algorithms, fuzzy techniques, logistic regression, edge
    detection, color detection, principal component analysis\\
    13.& 
    Herbicide& 
    Remote sensing in general, optical cameras and photo-detectors& 
    Fuzzy techniques, discriminant analysis\\
    14.& 
    Fruit grading& 
    Optical cameras and photo-detectors, monochrome images with
    different illuminations& 
    K-means clustering, image fusion, color histogram techniques, machine
    learning (esp. SVM), Bayesian discriminant analysis, Bayes filtering, linear
    discriminant analysis\\
    15.& 
    Packaged food and food products –
    identification of contaminants, diseases
    or defects, bruise detection& 
    X-ray imaging (or transmitted light), CCD cameras, monochrome
    images with different illuminations, thermal cameras, multi-spectral
    and hyperspectral NIR-based imaging& 
    3D vision, invariance, pattern recognition and image modality, 
    decision trees, fusion, feature extraction techniques with FFT, standard
    Bayesian discriminant analysis, feature analysis, color, shape and geometric
    features using discrimination analysis, pulsed-phase thermography\\
    16.& 
    Crop hail damage& 
    Multi-spectral imaging, polarimetric radar imagery& 
    Linear and exponential regression analysis, unsupervised image classification\\
    17.& 
    Agricultural expansion and
    intensification& 
    Satellite remote sensing in general& 
    Wavelet-based filtering\\
    18.& 
    Greenhouse monitoring& 
    Optical and thermal cameras& 
    Linear and exponential regression analysis, unsupervised classification,
    NDVI, IR thermography\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
}
\clearpage


2. \kant[4-6]
\end{document}
```

**OPTION 2**  Using a `longtable`  when it is a really long table.

Requires generating the long table before and then inserting the resulting pdf into `elsarticle`

(1) Use this  code `longtablelandscape.tex` to generate `longtablelandscape.pdf`, three pages long.

```
% File longtablelandscape.tex

\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
    paperwidth=210mm,
    paperheight=297mm,
    textheight=622pt,
    textwidth=468pt,
    centering,
    headheight=10pt,
    headsep=12pt,
    footskip=12pt,
    footnotesep=14pt plus 2pt minus 12pt,
}

\RequirePackage{pdflscape}
\RequirePackage{afterpage}
\RequirePackage{longtable}

\RequirePackage{caption}
\RequirePackage{array}

\begin{document}
    
\pagestyle{empty}
\input{landscape_template}
\end{document}
```

The `longtable` is in this file, named `landscape_template.tex`

```
%%% File landscape_template.tex

\newlength{\twidth}
\setlength{\twidth}{\dimexpr \textheight+\headheight+\topsep} % total usable page height

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\small\raggedright \arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\afterpage{%
    \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
        \appendix           
        \section{Application in Agriculture}            
            \begin{longtable}{L{3ex} L{0.20\twidth} L{0.35\twidth}L{0.42\twidth}@{}}
%               \caption{\Large Dimension I: Transcendental logic} \label{D1} \\                        
            No. & Application in Agriculture&   Remote sensing&     Techniques for data analysis\\ \hline
            \endfirsthead           
            
             1.&     Soil and vegetation/crop mapping&   Hyperspectral imaging (satellite and airborne), multi‐spectral
            imaging (satellite), synthetic aperture radar (SAR)&    Image fusion, SVM, end-member extraction algorithm, co-polarized phase
            differences (PPD), linear polarizations (HH, VV, HV), distance-based    classification, decision trees, linear mixing models, logistic regression, ANN,     NDVI\\
            2.&     Leaf area index and crop canopy&    Hyperspectral imaging (airborne), multi‐spectral imaging (airborne) & Linear regression analysis, NDVI\\
            3.&     Crop phenology&     Satellite remote sensing (general)& Wavelet-based filtering, Fourier transforms, NDVI\\
            4.& 
            Crop height, estimation of yields,
            fertilizers' effect and biomass& 
            Light Detection and Ranging (LIDAR), hyperspectral and multi-
            spectral imaging, SAR, red-edge camera, thermal infrared& 
            Linear and exponential regression analysis, linear polarizations (VV),
            wavelet-based filtering, vegetation indices (NDVI, ICWSI), ANN\\
            5.& 
            Crop monitoring& 
            Satellite remote sensing (hyperspectral and multi-spectral imaging),
            NIR camera, SAR& 
            Stepwise discriminate analysis (DISCRIM) feature extraction, linear
            regression analysis, co-polarized phase differences (PPD), linear polarizations
            (HH, VV, HV, RR and RL), classification and regression tree analysis\\
            6.& 
            Identification of seeds and
            reorganization of species& 
            Remote sensing in general, cameras and photo-detectors,
            hyperspectral imaging& 
            Principal component analysis, feature extraction, linear regression analysis\\
            7.& 
            Soil and leaf nitrogen content and
            treatment, salinity detection& 
            Hyperspectral and multi-spectral imaging, thermal imaging& 
            Linear and exponential regression analysis\\
            8.& 
            Irrigation& 
            Satellite remote sensing (hyperspectral and multi-spectral imaging),
            red-edge camera, thermal infrared& 
            Image classification techniques (unsupervised clustering, density slicing with
            thresholds), decision trees, linear regression analysis, NDVI\\
            9.& 
            Plants water stress detection and drought
            conditions& 
            Satellite remote sensing (hyperspectral and multi-spectral imaging,
            radar images), thermal imaging, NIR camera, red-edge camera& 
            Fraunhofer Line Depth (FLD) principle, linear regression analysis, NDVI\\
            10.& 
            Water erosion assessment& 
            Satellite remote sensing (optical and radar images), SAR, NIR
            camera& 
            Interferometric SAR image processing, linear and exponential regression
            analysis, contour tracing, linear polarizations (HH, VV)\\
            11.& 
            Pest detection and management& 
            Hyperspectral and multi-spectral imaging, microwave remote
            sensing, thermal camera& 
            Image processing using sample imagery, linear and exponential regression
            analysis, statistical analysis, CEM nonlinear signal processing, NDVI\\
            12.& 
            Weed detection& 
            Remote sensing in general, optical cameras and photo-detectors,
            hyperspectral and multi-spectral imaging& 
            Pixel classification based on k-means clustering and Bayes classifier, feature
            extraction techniques with FFT and GLCM, wavelet-based classification and
            Gabor filtering, genetic algorithms, fuzzy techniques, logistic regression, edge
            detection, color detection, principal component analysis\\
            13.& 
            Herbicide& 
            Remote sensing in general, optical cameras and photo-detectors& 
            Fuzzy techniques, discriminant analysis\\
            14.& 
            Fruit grading& 
            Optical cameras and photo-detectors, monochrome images with
            different illuminations& 
            K-means clustering, image fusion, color histogram techniques, machine
            learning (esp. SVM), Bayesian discriminant analysis, Bayes filtering, linear
            discriminant analysis\\
            15.& 
            Packaged food and food products –
            identification of contaminants, diseases
            or defects, bruise detection& 
            X-ray imaging (or transmitted light), CCD cameras, monochrome
            images with different illuminations, thermal cameras, multi-spectral
            and hyperspectral NIR-based imaging& 
            3D vision, invariance, pattern recognition and image modality, 
            decision trees, fusion, feature extraction techniques with FFT, standard
            Bayesian discriminant analysis, feature analysis, color, shape and geometric
            features using discrimination analysis, pulsed-phase thermography\\
            16.& 
            Crop hail damage& 
            Multi-spectral imaging, polarimetric radar imagery& 
            Linear and exponential regression analysis, unsupervised image classification\\
            17.& 
            Agricultural expansion and
            intensification& 
            Satellite remote sensing in general& 
            Wavelet-based filtering\\
            18.& 
            Greenhouse monitoring& 
            Optical and thermal cameras& 
            Linear and exponential regression analysis, unsupervised classification,
            NDVI, IR thermography\\
             19.&     Soil and vegetation/crop mapping&   Hyperspectral imaging (satellite and airborne), multi‐spectral
            imaging (satellite), synthetic aperture radar (SAR)&    Image fusion, SVM, end-member extraction algorithm, co-polarized phase
            differences (PPD), linear polarizations (HH, VV, HV), distance-based    classification, decision trees, linear mixing models, logistic regression, ANN,     NDVI\\
            20.&     Leaf area index and crop canopy&    Hyperspectral imaging (airborne), multi‐spectral imaging (airborne) & Linear regression analysis, NDVI\\
            21.&     Crop phenology&     Satellite remote sensing (general)& Wavelet-based filtering, Fourier transforms, NDVI\\
            22.& 
            Crop height, estimation of yields,
            fertilizers' effect and biomass& 
            Light Detection and Ranging (LIDAR), hyperspectral and multi-
            spectral imaging, SAR, red-edge camera, thermal infrared& 
            Linear and exponential regression analysis, linear polarizations (VV),
            wavelet-based filtering, vegetation indices (NDVI, ICWSI), ANN\\
            23.& 
            Crop monitoring& 
            Satellite remote sensing (hyperspectral and multi-spectral imaging),
            NIR camera, SAR& 
            Stepwise discriminate analysis (DISCRIM) feature extraction, linear
            regression analysis, co-polarized phase differences (PPD), linear polarizations
            (HH, VV, HV, RR and RL), classification and regression tree analysis\\
            24.& 
            Identification of seeds and
            reorganization of species& 
            Remote sensing in general, cameras and photo-detectors,
            hyperspectral imaging& 
            Principal component analysis, feature extraction, linear regression analysis\\
            25.& 
            Soil and leaf nitrogen content and
            treatment, salinity detection& 
            Hyperspectral and multi-spectral imaging, thermal imaging& 
            Linear and exponential regression analysis\\
            26.& 
            Irrigation& 
            Satellite remote sensing (hyperspectral and multi-spectral imaging),
            red-edge camera, thermal infrared& 
            Image classification techniques (unsupervised clustering, density slicing with
            thresholds), decision trees, linear regression analysis, NDVI\\
            27.& 
            Plants water stress detection and drought
            conditions& 
            Satellite remote sensing (hyperspectral and multi-spectral imaging,
            radar images), thermal imaging, NIR camera, red-edge camera& 
            Fraunhofer Line Depth (FLD) principle, linear regression analysis, NDVI\\
            28.& 
            Water erosion assessment& 
            Satellite remote sensing (optical and radar images), SAR, NIR
            camera& 
            Interferometric SAR image processing, linear and exponential regression
            analysis, contour tracing, linear polarizations (HH, VV)\\
            29.& 
            Pest detection and management& 
            Hyperspectral and multi-spectral imaging, microwave remote
            sensing, thermal camera& 
            Image processing using sample imagery, linear and exponential regression
            analysis, statistical analysis, CEM nonlinear signal processing, NDVI\\
            30.& 
            Weed detection& 
            Remote sensing in general, optical cameras and photo-detectors,
            hyperspectral and multi-spectral imaging& 
            Pixel classification based on k-means clustering and Bayes classifier, feature
            extraction techniques with FFT and GLCM, wavelet-based classification and
            Gabor filtering, genetic algorithms, fuzzy techniques, logistic regression, edge
            detection, color detection, principal component analysis\\
            31.& 
            Herbicide& 
            Remote sensing in general, optical cameras and photo-detectors& 
            Fuzzy techniques, discriminant analysis\\
            32.& 
            Fruit grading& 
            Optical cameras and photo-detectors, monochrome images with
            different illuminations& 
            K-means clustering, image fusion, color histogram techniques, machine
            learning (esp. SVM), Bayesian discriminant analysis, Bayes filtering, linear
            discriminant analysis\\
            33.& 
            Packaged food and food products –
            identification of contaminants, diseases
            or defects, bruise detection& 
            X-ray imaging (or transmitted light), CCD cameras, monochrome
            images with different illuminations, thermal cameras, multi-spectral
            and hyperspectral NIR-based imaging& 
            3D vision, invariance, pattern recognition and image modality, 
            decision trees, fusion, feature extraction techniques with FFT, standard
            Bayesian discriminant analysis, feature analysis, color, shape and geometric
            features using discrimination analysis, pulsed-phase thermography\\
            34.& 
            Crop hail damage& 
            Multi-spectral imaging, polarimetric radar imagery& 
            Linear and exponential regression analysis, unsupervised image classification\\
            35.& 
            Agricultural expansion and
            intensification& 
            Satellite remote sensing in general& 
            Wavelet-based filtering\\
            36.& 
            Greenhouse monitoring& 
            Optical and thermal cameras& 
            Linear and exponential regression analysis, unsupervised classification,
            NDVI, IR thermography\\ \hline  
        \end{longtable}%    
    \end{landscape}%
}
```

(2) Insert the longtable into the main document `main.tex`

```
% File main.tex

\documentclass[final,3p,twocolumn,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\RequirePackage{kantlipsum}

%\usepackage{showframe} % to show the margins

\journal{Computers and Electronics in Agriculture}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}                 
    \title{The Title}                   
    \author{One Author}         
    \affiliation{organization={},
        addressline={}, 
        city={},
        postcode={}, 
        state={},
        country={}}         
    \begin{abstract}
        %% Text of abstract             
    \end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction }‎‎   
1.  \kant[1-4]  

\onecolumn\includepdf[pages={-},width=\textwidth, angle=90, pagecommand={}]{longtablelandscape.pdf}

\twocolumn 2. \kant[2-6]

\end{document}
```

This is the final output:

[image: a]